# Static import of static Nested class not working

Tags: java, loops, inner-classes, static-import

```
package com.foo;
public abstract class A {
    private functionA() {
    }
  static class B {
     A a;
     public functionB() {
       a.functionA();
     }
}
```

So, I need to test functionA() from a different package but I can't make any changes in class A, or the package com.foo that is the constraint. I am trying to do a static import so that I can access static nested class B from outside this package but it gives me the error of "cannot find symbol, symbol: static B, class A" I have tried import static com.foo.A.* also but on writing B.functionB() inside Test class I get the error "cannot find symbol B inside Test Class". Please find the Test class syntax below:

```
package com.foo.test;
import static com.foo.A.B;
public class Test {
   B.functionB(); 
}
```

Is there any other way that I can test functionA() or functionB() from outside the package?

Comment: Class `A` does not compile. `functionB` is not a static method. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You'd need an instance of `B` to call `functionB()`

Comment: This is just a sample code, can't put the actual code here, so class A compiles and function B calls function A using instance of A class only

Comment: yes, I would need an instance of B to call functionB I was trying out static import because it was showing that import static com.foo.A.B should work, but in my case it gives symbol not found error.

Comment: This worked for me.. not sure if this is what you were trying.
 1. B is a public static nested class within A 
 2. in other package, i imported `import foo.A`;
 3. then created new instance of class B using `new A.B()`, and this instance of B can call `functionB`

Comment: How does it work for you, i tried this initially but since they are in different package so the conventional way of accessing Inner clas Outer.Inner obj = new Outer.Inner() doesn't work, that's why i needed static import.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the outer class's instance method from a static inner class.

There are two ways you could go about this:

1. Rather than test the private function directly, call a public method that calls the private function and analyze the side effects. In fact, at the end of the day, sticking with public methods is better for black-box testing.
2. You can put your test class in the same package, but in a different source folder. This is how a lot of IDEs handle it by default (src/main/java for your main code, src/test/java for unit tests). Note that your functionA() method must be package protected instead of private for this (i.e. remove the private keyword).

That said, if you have your heart set on your current way, you can just make B and functionB public and add the static modifier to functionB, and it should work as long as functionB has access to an *instance* of A. Of course, this sort of defeats the point of making functionA private.

Comment: Hi, this code is actually already present and working, so functionB of class B is able to call outer class A's functionA. There are some bugs in functionA that i need to test and the test should be in a different package ( constraints) and also I can't define a public function in A and call functionA() from that. I need to do everything in the Test class only which needs to be in a different package.

Comment: I fail to see how this works. When I put your code in my IDE, it warns me that "non-static method functionA() cannot be referenced from a static context." We are talking about pure Java, and not something like Groovy, right?

Comment: ok, so there is slight error, class B accesses it by an instance of class A, so it is basically a.functionA() where a is an instance of class A, A a;

Comment: That should work a bit better. Now, just make functionB static and class B public and you should be good to go. Of course, that means that functionA isn't really private anymore and literally anything can access functionA through B.